# How to catch error code from one shell script into another shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, sh

The thing is :
I have one python file 
I am executing it using a shell script named `run.sh`
**content of  run.sh**

```
python test.py
```

and in python file I am testing for something and if it is not matching i am exiting using sys.exit(1). I am able to catch this in `run.sh` using `$?`
But The problem is there is a master shell script ,

```
master.sh
```

and `run.sh` is called from `master.sh` . 
Mater.sh calls multiple shell script from inside.
i.e

```
sh run.sh
sh test.sh
```

I want to ensure that if run.sh fails , i.e if python file exits with sys.exit(1) then it is catched in master.sh and it doesn't run the next shell script i.e it should then not run the test.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing you did for `run.sh`, catch the `return_code`

in master.sh

```
sh run.sh
if [ $? == 0 ]
then sh test.sh
else
exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the script this way: `sh run.sh ¦¦ exit 1`

Comment: is this function similar to  ?

sh run.sh
if [ $? == 0 ]
then sh test.sh
else
exit 1
fi